# Does SF support two ADFS servers in different forests providing SSO?

Tags: administration, single-sign-on, saml

We are trying to use SSO on 2 different domains that will connect to our SF org.Currently we have ADFS SAML setup to 1 but we adding another one.
The question is, does SF support two ADFS servers in different forests providing SSO?

Thanks,
K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Each ADFS instance is going to become a different identity provider in Salesforce. You will have to be careful with URLs, entity IDs and issuers but it does work.